# How do I efficiently delete from a join table with extra columns in spring data jpa?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities (User, NewsItem) and a many-to-many relationship (AccessedBy) between their id's

Here is the User Entity :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "news_user")
public class User {

private UUID id;
private Set<AccessedBy> accessors = new HashSet<AccessedBy>();

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH}, orphanRemoval = true)
public Set<AccessedBy> getAccessors() {
    return accessors;
}

public void setAccessors(Set<AccessedBy> accessors) {
    this.accessors = accessors;
}
}
```

Here is the News Entity :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "news_item")
public class NewsItem {

private UUID id;
private Set<AccessedBy> accessors = new HashSet<>();

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "newsItem", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH}, orphanRemoval = true)
public Set<AccessedBy> getAccessors() {
    return accessors;
}

public void setAccessors(Set<AccessedBy> accessors) {
    this.accessors = accessors;
}
}
```

Here is the relationship between them (AccessedBy) :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accessed_by")
@IdClass(AccessedById.class)
public class AccessedBy {

private User user;
private NewsItem newsItem;
private Boolean bookmarked;
private Boolean read;
private Boolean deleted;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "news_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public NewsItem getNewsItem() {
    return newsItem;
}

public void setNewsItem(NewsItem newsItem) {
    this.newsItem = newsItem;
}

@Column(name = "bookmarked", nullable = false)
public Boolean getBookmarked() {
    return bookmarked;
}

public void setBookmarked(Boolean bookmarked) {
    this.bookmarked = bookmarked;
}

@Column(name = "read", nullable = false)
public Boolean getRead() {
    return read;
}

public void setRead(Boolean read) {
    this.read = read;
}

@Column(name = "deleted", nullable = false)
public Boolean getDeleted() {
    return deleted;
}

public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
    this.deleted = deleted;
}
}
```

Let's say the user wants to bookmark a news item. For bookmarking I enter a record in the AccessedBy table with bookmark property set to true. And I want to remove the record from the AccessedBy table in case the user unbookmarks it. How can I do that efficiently?

What I tried :-

I tried to remove the AccessedBy object that I inserted earlier from the HashSet of both the entities but the object doesn't get removed as seen from debugging.

How I am tying to delete :-

```
User user = checkUser(authorization);
    NewsItem newsItem = newsRepository.findByUniqueId(newsId);
    AccessedBy accessedBy = new AccessedBy(user, newsItem, true, false, false);
    user.getAccessors().remove(accessedBy);
   newsItem.getAccessors().remove(accessedBy);
    userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    newsRepository.saveAndFlush(newsItem);
```

checkuser() checks for basic auth and returns the user from db.

Comment: try to use cascades

Comment: @IharSadounikau I used the merge cascade type for adding into the table. What is the ideal cascade type to be used for delete?

Comment: I will use REMOVE in this case

Comment: @IharSadounikau tried the same but no luck. I have edited the question to add the code to remove from the Set for both the entities, Can you verify if this is the ideal way? If not, can you tell me how to do it?